# How to Transpose Tikz Graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, graphs

I want to transpose the Tikz Graph below. My goal is to get the graph on the far right so I need to transpose the middle graph.

**How can I transpose the Tikz graph?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph {
1 -- 14 -- 13 -- 12 -- 14{} -- 1{};
2 -- 24 -- 23 -- 21 -- 24{} -- 2{};
3 -- 31 -- 32 -- 34 -- 35 -- 3{};
4 -- 41 -- 42 -- 43 -- 41{} -- 42{} -- 4{};
5 -- 5{} -- 53 -- 5{}{} -- 5{}{}{};

14 -- [bend right] 41;
13 -- 31;
24{} -- 42{};
14{} -- [bend right] 41{};
35 -- [bend right] 53;
24 -- 42;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the manual in the section `Placement on a Grid`. There the `chain shift` and `group shift` keys are described, and can be used to good effect here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [group shift=(0:1), chain shift=(270:1)] {
1 -- 14 -- 13 -- 12 -- 14{} -- 1{};
2 -- 24 -- 23 -- 21 -- 24{} -- 2{};
3 -- 31 -- 32 -- 34 -- 35 -- 3{};
4 -- 41 -- 42 -- 43 -- 41{} -- 42{} -- 4{}; 
5 -- 5{} -- 53 -- 5{}{} -- 5{}{}{};

14 -- [bend right] 41;
13 -- 31;
24{} -- 42{};
14{} -- [bend right] 41{};
35 -- [bend right] 53;
24 -- 42;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]